# Ubuntu 11.10 not suspending automatically

Tags: 11.10, power-management, gnome-settings-daemon

New:
After digging around a bit more, I found out the problem is much more that the system is not suspending on its own, although suspending manually (shutdown->suspend) works well.
I used the suspend after 5 mins setting on both ac and power from the power settings menu.

The only "solution" I could find for that problem was linked from another thread :
http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug 
Did not work for me.

Old:
If I manually (with gconf-editor) set sleep-inactive-timeout to another value other than the 5/10/3/1 from the power manager, the settings will be ignored (= no suspending at all).
I set it to 10 and waited 20 seconds. Tried logging in/out and  rebooting still the same.
Also restarted (killed) the gnome-settings-daemon, still the same.

Am I missing something? If I understand it correctly the gnome-power-daemon (or whatever the name was in older releases) is now completely replaced by the gnome-settings-daemon.
Or am I missing an additional package?

Here comes all my settings-daemon dconf-settings:

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-hibernate 'hibernate'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'interactive'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'hibernate'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 30
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-ac false
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-battery true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-time 10
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power notify-perhaps-recall true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-action 2
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical 3
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-low 10
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power priority 1
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-battery 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 10
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 10
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-action 120
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-critical 300
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-low 1200
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy true
```

Comment: Sounds like you've done some good work hunting down a bug! That's very nice. We log bugs on Launchpad.net, however. This site isn't suitable for that, but only for Questions and Answers.

Comment: I don't think its a bug , because it works on other peoples machines. Anyway I reported it here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/989484. Does anybody know a workaround for that, like a third-party power manager or something similar?

Comment: Not sure if you saw this answer, but after months of frustration, it fixed it for me. http://askubuntu.com/a/180505/53508

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround. It requires xprintidle to be installed:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($idletime,$suspendtime);
while (1==1){
    $idletime= qx/xprintidle/;
    $suspendtime = qx/gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout/;
    if ($idletime/1000 >= $suspendtime){
    exec("pmi action suspend");
    }

    print "idle: $idletime\n suspendtime: $suspendtime\n";

    sleep 180;
}
```

Put this in your shell in the background or start it on login.