# Unity won't suspend on inactivity

Tags: 12.04, power-management, suspend

Running 12.04.   I can manually suspend the system and wake it up again, but I can't get it to suspend on inactivity automatically.

I have it set to "Suspend when inactive for" 10 minutes in systems settings > power. It just blanks the screen, but does not suspend.

Info as requested.  Left system untouched at 18:30 with suspend set to 10 minutes.

kern.log and dmesg had nothing new in them.

sys.log had these extra lines

```
Aug 23 18:34:26 Ubuntu-desktop AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting due to inactivity
Aug 23 18:34:26 Ubuntu-desktop AptDaemon: INFO: Quitting was requested
Aug 23 18:39:01 Ubuntu-desktop CRON[3228]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
```

Comment: After making sure your system attempts to suspend/blank screen *at least once*, without rebooting, please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): file(s): `/var/log/kern.log`, `/var/log/syslog`, command(s): `dmesg`

Comment: Very little extra info was posted to the log files, but I have edited my question with what was added as the system went into blank screen with no-suspend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally managed to get it to suspend fully on inactivity.

In addition to  System Settings > Power set to turn off after 10 minutes,   I had to ALSO set  System Settings > Brightness and Lock   to turn off the screen after 10 minutes.

Surely if these 2 settings are dependent on each other they should be together in one section of System Settings?  The way they interact seems wrong, and the Systems Settings > Power section doesn't hint or warn that it can't be set independently.

Comment: I was having similar problems with my system not sleeping. I took your advice here, and it solved my problems. The thing is, now it seems to work perfectly fine if I revert all my settings! Perhaps the toggle was all that was needed. FWIW, I can have the 2 settings different now. Via dconf-editor, I also toggled org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen (originally true) and could leave both org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled and ubuntu-lock-on-suspend as either true or false.

Comment: Also, note that the timing is not correct. e.g. (via dconf) I can set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac and sleep-inactive-ac-timeout to 5 and 5, and they'll work at 30 and 70. Similarly, 60 and 60 results in the computer suspending around 90 seconds.

Comment: I just filed a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/1055874) for this second issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue on 12.04, fixed by setting org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power `sleep-display-battery` to a value lower than the value of `sleep-inactive-battery-timeout`.